# Outlook addin working in Outlook Online, but doesn't show up in Outlook client

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Recently I have developed an Outlook add-in which will have two dropdown buttons and a taskpane button. The add-in works fine in the Outlook online. But the add-in is not displayed in the Outlook client ribbon.

If I remove one of the dropdown buttons from my add-in, it is working fine in all the environments.

I read that currently only one level of dropdown are allowed but nothing related to number of dropdowns. Is there any restriction on the number of dropdown controls to be used in the manifest ?

I am running on Office 365 Pro Plus and Outlook client version is 1804 (Build 9226.2114)

I am using VersionOverridesV1_0 and below controls:

```
        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">

          <Group id="msgReadGroup">
            <Label resid="groupLabel" />

            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="msgReadMenuButton">
              <Label resid="msgReadMenuLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="msgReadMenuLabelTitle" />
                <Description resid="msgReadMenuSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="mail16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="mail32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="mail80" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="Item1">
                  <Label resid="Item1Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Item1LabelTitle" />
                    <Description resid="Item1SuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Function1</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>

                <Item id="Item2">
                  <Label resid="Item2Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Item2LabelTitle" />
                    <Description resid="Item2SuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Function1</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </Control>

            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="meetingReadMenu">
              <Label resid="meetingReadLabel" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="meetingReadMenuTitle" />
                <Description resid="meetingReadMenuSuperTipDescr" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="meetingItem1">
                  <Label resid="meetingItem1Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="meetingItem1Title" />
                    <Description resid="meetingItem1SUSuperTipDescr" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Function1</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="meetingItem2">
                  <Label resid="meetingItem2Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="meetingItem2Title" />
                    <Description resid="meetingItem2SuperTipDescr" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Function1</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                </Items>
              </Control>


            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="taskpaneButton">
                <Label resid="taskpaneButtonLabel" />
                <Supertip>
                  <Title resid="taskpaneButtonTitle" />
                  <Description resid="taskpaneButtonSuperTipDescr" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                </Icon>
                <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                  <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                </Action>
              </Control>

            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="ReadMenuButton">
              <Label resid="ReadMenu" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="ReadMenuSuperTipTitle" />
                <Description resid="ReadMenuSuperTipDescription" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="help16" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="help32" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="help80" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <Item id="ReadItem1">
                  <Label resid="ReadItem1Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ReadItem1Title" />
                    <Description resid="ReadItem1SuperTipDescr" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Function1</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>

                <Item id="ReadItem2">
                  <Label resid="ReadItem2Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ReadItem2Title" />
                    <Description resid="ReadItem2SuperTipDescr" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>Function1</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </Control>                 
            <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
          </Group>
        </OfficeTab>
      </ExtensionPoint>
```

Comment: Can you share the manifest xml that you are using to generate your ribbon buttons?

Comment: Hi Team, modified the question with the controls

Comment: So I tried adding multiple "menu" dropdowns and it works for me. Can you upload a more complete manifest, with full resources and everything? If you need to sanitize some HTML URLs that's ok, but the more complete it is the better it is for us to debug.It's likely something else in the manifest that is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi Team, got it resolved. I was using the same group id for controls and after changing it  the issue resolved.